# Capistrano 3 removing .git folder

Tags: git, jenkins, capistrano, capistrano3

Our code uses the git repository in order to get the version of the app (we make something like `{git-tag}-build{git-hash}` and we're using Capistrano to deploy our application.

However, using Capistrano v3.0 (ran by Jenkins) I found that the git repository is removed.

I tried to make something similar to this:

```
namespace :environment do
    desc 'Copies .git folder'
    task :copy_git do
        on roles(:app) do
            within release_path do
                execute :mkdir, ".git"
                execute :cp, "-R * .git/"
            end
        end
    end
end
```

But as you may understand, it doesn't work.

This is the issue I get:

`Could not get version string (no version file and`git describe`failed)`.

Any idea on how to solve this or how to have the .git folder inside the release_path? Any other idea on versioning is acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the missing `.git` folder is that deployment happens via `git archive | tar -xf` (simplified).

Upon deployment, `release_path` contains a file called `REVISION` within which you can find the git hash of the deployed code. You can use this to get the exact revision.

I generally recommend that you stick a variable in your codebase to track the release version, e.g. 1.0.0. This is how the RubyGems template does it. This way, your code version isn't tied to your version control system.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great answer. Didn't know about the existence of the REVISION file. I ended doing a mix between what we had and what you suggested.

On one side, we implement a static versioning (just as RubyGems), but we still need the build, so I managed to use the hash provided on the REVISION file. So it looks like {static, ie 1.0.4}-build{REVISION}.