# Could not get version string (no version file and `git describe` failed)

Tags: git, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead, laravel-7

I run the Laravel Project Using Laravel Homestead.

Sometimes I have faced issue with `version string` and I can't run my project.

[image]

Please help me to out of this issue.

Comment: Would https://stackoverflow.com/a/32959017/6309 help?

Comment: i don't think above answer help for my issue. @VonC